# Integrating Simplesamlphp with Liferay for SSO

Tags: liferay, single-sign-on, liferay-6, simplesamlphp

I'm trying to implement **SSO** for Liferay and i want to use **Simplesamlphp** as an **Identity provider**  and **Liferay** will be the **Service Provider**. I have redirected the sign In in Liferay to my Simplesamlphp site by adding **auth.login.url=http://myloginappjcq.com** in the portal-ext.properties file. But when i click on sign In it redirects to my website myloginappjcq.com. In my Website i have added a link to my Liferay site. There are links to  other applications as well in my website which are built using PHP. When i click on these links the application will be authenticated with the username and password which was given during the time of login. But, When i click on the Liferay Link it is not authenticated and it shows the sign In Page again.

Is there a documentation which explains **Liferay integration with SImplesamlphp.**

Thanks

Comment: "I have made a change and don't care to tell everybody what I changed. Now it doesn't work. I won't tell what I already did and what the current (non-working) outcome is." Seriously: You'll have to give *a lot* more information if you're expecting help. Simply asking for a tutorial isn't in scope for Stackoverflow.

Comment: I have re framed my question now

Comment: Are you using Liferay's SAML plugin? Which version of Liferay are you using?

Comment: No I'm not using Liferay SAML Plugin, I'm using Liferay 6.2 CE.

Comment: The name "simplesamlphp" suggests that this product is using SAML as the protocol for SSO. I don't see how you would use SAML without a plugin interpreting SAML on the Liferay side of things. The website mentions that it works together with other SSO products, but note that this doesn't imply that it mimics their protocol. I don't know enough about that product to recommend how to us it - other than trying it with Liferay's SAML plugin. Of course - as that's EE-only - it would imply upgrading to EE.

Comment: Why is nobody ever crossreferencing if they ask the same question in multiple locations? https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/46081775

Comment: Ok, I need to configure Liferay with SAML 2.0 Plugin so that it can  connect any Idp i want. I found out that SAML 2.0 plugin is available only for Liferay EE. Is there a SAML 2.0 CE plugin available.